# Adding a Javascript function interferes with existing scroll event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener

For the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Blueprints</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="masthead">
        <nav>
            <a href="" class="logo"><span>Blue</span>prints</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <article>
            <section id="section-start">
            <p class="kicker">Website</p>
            <h1>Story Design System</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur</b> adipiscing elit. Nam varius quam ac <strong>elementum</strong> tristique. Suspendisse fringilla rhoncus velit in scelerisque. Donec nulla nisl, blandit <i>vitae finibus</i> non, elementum id dui.</p>
            </section>
            <section id="sample-heading">
            <h2>Sample Heading</h2>
            <p>Praesent eleifend massa velit, eu lacinia purus laoreet non. Quisque non egestas nibh. Duis et sodales nulla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut pharetra justo lorem, quis semper enim convallis ut. Vivamus Bi Directional enim, consequat vel massa sit amet, posuere dapibus dolor.</p>
            </section>
            <section id="section-sample-heading">
            <h2>Heading 2 Bi Directional</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <code>consectetur</code> adipiscing elit. Nam varius quam ac <strong>elementum</strong> tristique. Suspendisse fringilla rhoncus velit in scelerisque. Donec nulla nisl, blandit <i>vitae finibus</i> non, elementum id dui. Praesent sed sollicitudin nibh, non facilisis tellus.</p>
            <ol>
                <li>Praesent sed sollicitudin nibh, non facilisis tellus. Curabitur interdum rhoncus metus, in sollicitudin felis fermentum eget. Integer ac efficitur tortor.</li>
                <li>Suspendisse ipsum sapien, posuere a fermentum non, interdum sit amet orci. Aenean lobortis sapien eu ipsum porttitor, vitae ornare ex accumsan.</li>
                <li>Duis auctor eget turpis non efficitur.</li>
            </ol>
            </section>
            <section id="section-code-example">
            <h2>Code Example</h2>
            <p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut maximus, nibh at pretium dapibus, ipsum neque sodales nunc, laoreet interdum. Morbi at euismod lectus.</p>
            <h3>Heading 3</h3>
            <p>Sed id ullamcorper augue, vulputate convallis ligula. Cras eros massa, aliquam vitae quam a, suscipit tempor odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur et consequat nisi. Curabitur egestas dictum lacus. Pellentesque ut nulla eu dolor laoreet rhoncus ut ut lorem.</p>
            <h3>Heading 3</h3>
            <p>Phasellus et mi suscipit, ultrices lacus eget, ullamcorper massa. Morbi ultrices porttitor lectus. Pellentesque non bibendum erat. Suspendisse gravida erat non nunc porttitor accumsan. Nam suscipit sem nec sollicitudin dapibus. Suspendisse vulputate non arcu non rutrum.</p>
            </blockquote>
            </section>
            <section id="section-templates">
            <h2>Templates</h2>
            <p>Phasellus et mi suscipit, ultrices lacus eget, ullamcorper massa. Morbi ultrices porttitor lectus. Pellentesque non bibendum erat. Suspendisse gravida erat non nunc porttitor accumsan. Nam suscipit sem nec sollicitudin dapibus. Suspendisse vulputate non arcu non rutrum.</p>
            </section>
            <section class="change-log" id="change-log">
                <h2>Change log</h2>
                <dl>
                    <dt>June 23, 2023</dt>
                    <dd>Added syntax for new image layout module and examples.</dd>
                    <dt>November 31, 2023</dt>
                    <dd>Page created.</dd>
                </dl>
            </section>
        </article>
        <nav class="article">
            <h1>Contents</h1>
            <ul id="section-list">
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <footer">
        <ol id="breadcrumbs">
            <li class="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Website</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Template elements</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
            <li>Story Design System</li>
        </ol>
        <div id="notices">
            <ul>
                <li>&copy; <span id="current-year"></span> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script>smartquotes();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to write Javascript to:

- Insert the copyright year into the `<span id="current-year">`
- Scan the document for all of the sections and update the <ul> element in the <nav class="article"> accordingly, building navigation links to each of the sections that contain the contents of the <h1> or <h2> elements in that section.
- Create an event listener on scroll that adds the class "active" to the li for the current section
- Scan the document for all of the text inside the wrapper element, replacing instances of "Bi Directional" with "Bi Directional"

This Javascript works for the first three cases listed above:

```
// Set copyright year
function setCopyrightYear() {
  var yearElement = document.getElementById('current-year');
  if (yearElement) {
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    yearElement.textContent = currentYear;
  }
}


// CREATE and RUN article nav ul
// Get the ul element
var ulElement = document.getElementById('section-list');

// Get all the sections in the document
var sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

// Create an array to store the corresponding li elements
var liElements = [];

// Iterate over the sections and add the text as new li elements with links
for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  var section = sections[i];

  // Create a new li element
  var liElement = document.createElement('li');

  // Create a new anchor element
  var anchorElement = document.createElement('a');

  // Set the href attribute of the anchor element to the corresponding section's id
  anchorElement.href = '#' + section.id;

  // Set the text of the anchor element to the text of the section's h2 or h1 element
  var headingElement = section.querySelector('h2') || section.querySelector('h1');
  anchorElement.innerText = headingElement.innerText;

  // Append the anchor element to the li element
  liElement.appendChild(anchorElement);

  // Append the li element to the ul element
  ulElement.appendChild(liElement);

  // Add the li element to the array
  liElements.push(liElement);
}

  //Set first li element to active
  liElements[0].classList.add('active');


// Function to update the active section
function updateActiveSection() {
  // Get the current scroll position
  var scrollPosition = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;

  // Iterate over the sections and find the active section
  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    var section = sections[i];
    var sectionOffsetTop = section.offsetTop;
    var sectionHeight = section.offsetHeight;

    // Check if the current scroll position is within the bounds of the section
    if (scrollPosition >= sectionOffsetTop && scrollPosition < sectionOffsetTop + sectionHeight) {
      // Remove the "active" class from all li elements
      for (var j = 0; j < liElements.length; j++) {
        liElements[j].classList.remove('active');
      }

      // Add the "active" class to the corresponding li element
      liElements[i].classList.add('active');
      break;
    }
  }
}

}

// Function to handle DOMContentLoaded event
function handleDOMContentLoaded() {
  // Call the necessary functions
  // Set the copyright year
  setCopyrightYear();  
}

  // Add event listener to the window scroll event
window.addEventListener('scroll', updateActiveSection);


// Check if DOMContentLoaded event has already fired
if (document.readyState === 'complete' || document.readyState === 'interactive') {
  handleDOMContentLoaded();
} else {
  // Add event listener to DOMContentLoaded event
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handleDOMContentLoaded);
}
```

When I try to add the function to add a nbsp; to Bi Directional, the scroll event listener stops working. Here is a sample of that code:

```
// Set copyright year
function setCopyrightYear() {
  var yearElement = document.getElementById('current-year');
  if (yearElement) {
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    yearElement.textContent = currentYear;
  }
}


// CREATE and RUN article nav ul
// Get the ul element
var ulElement = document.getElementById('section-list');

// Get all the sections in the document
var sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

// Create an array to store the corresponding li elements
var liElements = [];

// Iterate over the sections and add the text as new li elements with links
for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  var section = sections[i];

  // Create a new li element
  var liElement = document.createElement('li');

  // Create a new anchor element
  var anchorElement = document.createElement('a');

  // Set the href attribute of the anchor element to the corresponding section's id
  anchorElement.href = '#' + section.id;

  // Set the text of the anchor element to the text of the section's h2 or h1 element
  var headingElement = section.querySelector('h2') || section.querySelector('h1');
  anchorElement.innerText = headingElement.innerText;

  // Append the anchor element to the li element
  liElement.appendChild(anchorElement);

  // Append the li element to the ul element
  ulElement.appendChild(liElement);

  // Add the li element to the array
  liElements.push(liElement);
}

  //Set first li element to active
  liElements[0].classList.add('active');


// Function to update the active section
function updateActiveSection() {
  // Get the current scroll position
  var scrollPosition = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;

  // Iterate over the sections and find the active section
  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    var section = sections[i];
    var sectionOffsetTop = section.offsetTop;
    var sectionHeight = section.offsetHeight;

    // Check if the current scroll position is within the bounds of the section
    if (scrollPosition >= sectionOffsetTop && scrollPosition < sectionOffsetTop + sectionHeight) {
      // Remove the "active" class from all li elements
      for (var j = 0; j < liElements.length; j++) {
        liElements[j].classList.remove('active');
      }

      // Add the "active" class to the corresponding li element
      liElements[i].classList.add('active');
      break;
    }
  }
}



// Fix Bi Directional space breaks
function fixUTSWBreaks() {
  // Get all elements with the class "wrapper"
  var wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper');

  // Iterate over each wrapper element
  for (var i = 0; i < wrappers.length; i++) {
    var wrapper = wrappers[i];

    // Get the HTML content of the wrapper element
    var content = wrapper.innerHTML;

    // Replace "Bi Directional" with "Bi&nbsp;Directional" using a regular expression
    var modifiedContent = content.replace(/Bi Directional/g, 'Bi&nbsp;Directional');

    // Set the modified content back to the wrapper element
    wrapper.innerHTML = modifiedContent;
  }
}

// Function to handle DOMContentLoaded event
function handleDOMContentLoaded() {
  // Call the necessary functions
  // Set the copyright year
  setCopyrightYear();

  // Fix Bi Directional space breaks
  fixSpaceBreaks();
  
}

  // Add event listener to the window scroll event
window.addEventListener('scroll', updateActiveSection);


// Check if DOMContentLoaded event has already fired
if (document.readyState === 'complete' || document.readyState === 'interactive') {
  handleDOMContentLoaded();
} else {
  // Add event listener to DOMContentLoaded event
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handleDOMContentLoaded);
}
```

I suspect this may be caused by the fact that the fixSpaceBreaks function is updating the DOM and causing a problem with the scroll event listener, but I'm not sure.